# Useful Lemma For Morita Equivalence

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, projective-module

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pb-PpnLQyDc&index=18&list=PLS3WLIIQXmMLvfY5NOfWRs55x_H4lRTpj) at 36:50 the professor states that the homomorphism $\tilde\gamma$ exists because $S$ is projective.  Is she saying that $\tilde\gamma$ is a section?
  This isn't clear to me.  What property of projective modules should I be reviewing?

Comment: It's just the definition of projective https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_module

Comment: @JJR The lifting property definition?  If so, isn't the map $\tilde\gamma$ going the wrong way?  I.e., it should be going from $F(B)\to S$ not the other way around I would think?

Comment: Not by definition of projective, i.e. $S$ projective if for any epimorphism $f : M\to N$ and any $g: S\to N$ $\Rightarrow$ $\exists h:S\to M$ such that $g= fh$.